# FOSUserBundle : no route found for Security:Login

Tags: symfony, routes, fosuserbundle

I post a problem here few days ago : 
[FOSUserBundle: embedding the login form and choosing its template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040512/fosuserbundle-embedding-the-login-form-and-choosing-its-template)

But it's pretty complicated, and I think behind this problem, there is maybe a simple problem of route, so I think it's a good idea to create a parallel topic, delete all the modifications I do, and start with fresh new installation.

So, I install FOSUserBundle, I have a WelcomeBundle, which contains the several pages of my website, and I also create a fresh UserBundle, which only contains the User Entity for FOSUserBundle, nothing else (no override of anything).

In my rsWelcomeBundle, in my index.html.twig, I put this simple code :

```
{% extends "rsWelcomeBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title "Page d'accueil" %}

{%  block body %}
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well">
            <h2>Présentation du jeu</h2>
            <a href="{{ path('rsWelcomeBundle_homepage_inscription') }}" class="btn ">Je m'inscris !</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well">
            {% render "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

And I always have this error :

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No route found for "GET Security:login"") in rsWelcomeBundle:Homepage:index.html.twig at line 1.

If I put this line for the render part it's working.

```
{% render(controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:login")) %}
```

But why ??
In the documentation I never see we've to use "render(controller".
Why I can't use directly : render "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" ?

In app/config/routing.yml I have :

```
tuto_welcome:
    resource: "@rsWelcomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

In the UserBundle I don't have routing.yml.
In the WelcomeBundle I have this in routing.yml :

```
rsWelcomeBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "rsWelcomeBundle:Homepage:index" }
```

It's been two days I try to fix this problem, could you help me ?

Thanks a lot to everyone !

Comment: {% render "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" %} is the Symfony 2.0 way to render a subrequest. {% render(controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:login")) %} is the syntax for 2.1+. Both syntax basically mean the same exact thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
So if I saw everywhere the first version of this code it's because there is old post ?
I don't really understand, I don't find nowhere in the official documentation an exemple of use : render(controller...).
And I find that crazy that's the old version is not compatible with 2.1+ Oo !

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers

Comment: Ok, how I can choose your answer ?

Comment: Thanks, I will repost my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{% render "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" %}` is the Symfony 2.0 way to render a subrequest. `{{ render(controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:login")) }}` is the syntax for 2.1+. Both syntax basically mean the same exact thing.

Documentation about subrequests is here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{% render url('your url') %}` instead.